# Why can't I connect my EC2 instance to ElastiCache?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to execute this Python script in an EC2 instance:

```
import elasticache_auto_discovery

elasticache_config_endpoint = "<my-elasticache-cluster-endpoint>:6379"
nodes = elasticache_auto_discovery.discover(elasticache_config_endpoint)
print("nodes discovered")
```

However, the print statement never executes. Sometimes I get `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`, usually I get nothing.

The EC2 instance and ElastiCache Redis cluster have the same VPC ID and Security group ID. The ElastiCache Redis cluster has a subnet group name attached to the same VPC ID.

The EC2 instance uses an IAM role with AmazonElastiCacheFullAccess policy attached. The role is assigned a permissions boundary that denies "Limited: Write" and allows "Full: Read, List, Tagging Limited: Write".

If I run the script with a nonsense string for `elasticache_config_endpoint` I get `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`.

Comment: Can you add SG config?

Comment: Security Group config? I don't know how to add that without revealing confidential info. As I mentioned in the question, the EC2 instance and ElastiCache cluster use the same security group. Is there something I should check for in the security group?

Comment: Merely having the same Security Group does not mean that resources can communicate with each other. Security Groups are **applied to each resource individually**. If you want them to communicate, you'll either need to permit the Security Group to receive Inbound connections from itself, or you could use separate Security Groups with rules that permit communication.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I had already added an inbound rule to the Security Group to receive communications from itself on port 6379 (the port that the ElastiCache cluster uses). Do I need to add any other rules to the Security Group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, at least in a limited sense. I created a new Elasticache cluster with Encryption in transit and Encryption at rest both disabled and then I was able to execute the Python snippet given in my question using the new cluster's endpoint.